# Solving $\cos(2x)-\sin(x)= 0$ within the domain $[0,2\pi]$. Why am I missing some solutions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I‘m trying to figure this one out:

> Solve for $x$ within the domain $[0,2\pi]$:
>   $$\cos(2x)-\sin(x)= 0$$

I figured this is $\sin(x)=-1$ and $\sin(x) = \frac 12$, which, when taking the $\arcsin$, gives $x=\frac{\pi}6$ and $x=-\frac{\pi}2$.

Now my question is:

> I‘m supposed to get $\dfrac{\pi}6$, $\dfrac{5\pi}6$, $\dfrac{3\pi}2$, but adding $2\pi$ gets me only $\dfrac{\pi}6$, $\dfrac{3\pi}2$, $\dfrac{7\pi}2$ within the $[0,2\pi]$ domain.

Any idea what I‘m doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you mean $[0, 2]$ or $[0, 2\pi]$?  Also, I assume you meant solve for $x$.

Comment: Editing it now, thanks! I meant 0 to 2 pi. And yes, solving for x is what I meant.

Comment: When you type an operation such as $\sin x$, type \sin x when you are in math mode so that the operation does not look the same as a variable.

Comment: Will do! Thanks again for your answer. I guess I need to consider the reflections as well. Not just the simple +-2pi method..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\cos(2x) - \sin x & = 0\\
1 - 2\sin^2x - \sin x & = 0\\
1 - \sin x - 2\sin^2x & = 0\\
1 - 2\sin x + \sin x - 2\sin^2x & = 0\\
1(1 - 2\sin x) + \sin x(1 - 2\sin x) & = 0\\
(1 + \sin x)(1 - 2\sin x) & = 0
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
1 + \sin x & = 0 &  1 - 2\sin x & = 0\\
\sin x & = -1 & -2\sin x & = -1\\
& & \sin x & = \frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}
Consider the diagram below.

[image: symmetry_diagram_for_sine_and_diagram]

The sine of an angle in standard position (vertex at the origin and initial side on the positive $x$-axis) is the $y$-coordinate of the point where the terminal side of the angle intersects the unit circle.  Two angles have the same sine if their terminal sides intersect the unit circle at points with the same $y$-coordinate.  Such angles are symmetric with respect to the $y$-axis. Thus, $\sin\theta = \sin\varphi$ if $\varphi = \pi - \theta$.  Any two coterminal angles will also have the same sine.  Hence, $\sin\theta = \sin\varphi$ implies 
$$\varphi = \theta + 2k\pi, k \in \mathbb{Z}$$
or 
$$\varphi = \pi - \theta + 2k\pi, k \in \mathbb{Z}$$ 
You found that a particular solution of the equation $\sin x = -1$ is 
$$x = \arcsin(-1) = -\frac{\pi}{2}$$
Hence, all solutions of that equation have the form
\begin{align*}
\theta & = -\frac{\pi}{2} + 2k\pi, k \in \mathbb{Z} & \theta &  = \pi - \left(-\frac{\pi}{2}\right) + 2k\pi\\
       & & & = \frac{3\pi}{2} + 2k\pi
\end{align*}
If you list the solutions, you will notice that both equations yield the same set of solutions.  The only one within the interval $[0, 2\pi]$ is $\dfrac{3\pi}{2}$.

You found that one solution of the equation $\sin x = \dfrac{1}{2}$ is $$x = \arcsin\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) = \frac{\pi}{6}$$  Hence,  the general solution is
\begin{align*}
x & = \frac{\pi}{6} + 2k\pi, k \in \mathbb{Z} & x & = \pi - \frac{\pi}{6} + 2k\pi, k \in \mathbb{Z}\\
  & & & = \frac{5\pi}{6} + 2k\pi, k \in \mathbb{Z}
\end{align*}
Of these angles, the only ones in the interval $[0, 2\pi]$ are $\dfrac{\pi}{6}$ and $\dfrac{5\pi}{6}$.

By only considering the arcsine of the angle, you missed the angle with the same sine that is obtained by reflection in the $y$-axis.  There is only one such angle within each period if the terminal side of the angle lies on the $y$-axis (as is the case for $\theta = -\frac{\pi}{2}$) and two such angles otherwise (as is the case for $\theta = \frac{\pi}{6}$).

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I think I made a huge mistake though... the question asks „within the domain [0.2pi] is the given function $cos(2x)-sin(x)$. Not sure if there is a difference to how I worded it..... if so, really sorry!

Comment: @user549904 There is no difference, this answer still works

Comment: I had the simple +-2pi idea, I guess I was wrong.

Comment: That is a common mistake when students first learn to solve trigonometric equations.  However, you asked a good question and learned why your approach does not work for sine.  For cosine, $\cos\theta = \cos\varphi$ implies $\varphi = \pm \theta + 2k\pi, k \in \mathbb{Z}$ (symmetry with respect to the $x$-axis and coterminal angles).  For tangent, $\tan\theta = \tan\varphi$ implies $\varphi = \theta + k\pi$ (since tangent assumes each real number once within each period and has period $\pi$).

Answer (score 1):

You are correct to add $2 \pi$ to $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ to get the angle $\frac{3\pi}{2} \in [0,2 \pi]$.

You shouldn't add $2\pi$ to $\frac{\pi}{6}$; that's already an angle in $[0,2\pi].$

Observe that the angle $\frac{5\pi}{6},$ the reflection of $\frac{\pi}{6}$ in the $y-$axis, also gives the same sine value.  (Look at the unit circle: the points corresponding to these angles have the same $y$-value.)

Whereas, $\frac{3\pi}{2}$ corresponds to a $y$-value of $-1$, and there is no other angle in $[0,2\pi]$ which does.